# Any (free) Lisp implementation to support unicode collation (UCA; ISO 1465)?

Tags: unicode, lisp, collation

I’m new to Lisp and I have some project in mind for practice -- just that it might involve heavy string sorting in a couple of different languages and scripts. Hence my question:

· Is there a free Lisp out there that supports ISO 1465 unicode collation?[1]

(All my googling didn’t yield much info so far but maybe I just don’t know where to look ….)

Thanks in advance and please don’t hesitate to give negative answers if accurate;-), Ph. G.

[1] http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c044872_ISO_IEC_14651_2007(E).zip

Comment: The only UCA implementations I'm aware of are the ICU one for C, C++, and Java, plus the Perl one.

Comment: @tchrist I didn’t know things were so bad. Some document I found while googling claims that Allegro CL does UCA from the standard tables. [1](http://www.common-lisp.com/support/documentation/8.2/doc/iacl.htm#collation-1) But it’s way above my budget …

Comment: I don't know, but if you can't find anything native, there's always FFI.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I didn't face with any `LISP` application in this field, there are **ICU** and other tools but I recommand you touse **http://unicode.codeplex.com** it is written with c# and provided an **API** to get Char informatin. I know that it's not what you are looking for but I'm not sure you can find one.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the open-source "babel" Common Lisp library could help you out.